# Tensorflow custom loss function - can't get samples of y_pred and y_true in loss function

Tags: python-3.x, lstm, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, loss-function

I'm running an LSTM network that works fine (TF 2.0). My problem starts when trying to modify the loss function.
I planed to adjust some data manipulation over 'y_true' and 'y_pred' but since TF force to maintain the data as tensors (and not convert it to Pandas or NumPy) it is challenging.
To get better control of the data inside the loss function I've simulated tf.keras.losses.mae function.

**My goal was to be able to see the data ('y_true' and 'y_pred') so I can make my desire adjustments.**

The original function:

```
def mean_absolute_error(y_true, y_pred):
  y_pred = ops.convert_to_tensor(y_pred)
  y_true = math_ops.cast(y_true, y_pred.dtype)
  return K.mean(math_ops.abs(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)
```

And after adjustments for debugging:

```
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
from tensorflow.python.ops import math_ops
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
def mean_absolute_error_test(y_true, y_pred):
     global temp_true
     temp_true=y_true
     print(y_true)
     y_pred = ops.convert_to_tensor(y_pred)
     y_true = math_ops.cast(y_true, y_pred.dtype)
     return K.mean(math_ops.abs(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)
```

when I run model.compile and print y_true I get:
Tensor("dense_target:0", shape=(None, None), dtype=float32)

type=tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor

Does anyone know how can I see 'y_pred' and 'y_true' or what am I missing?
Seems like I can't see samples of y_true or the data is empty.

The main code part:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout,Dense
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
K.clear_session()

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(20,activation='relu',input_shape=(look_back,len(training_columns)),recurrent_dropout=0.4))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=test2,experimental_run_tf_function=False)# mse,mean_squared_logarithmic_error
num_epochs = 20
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=3)
history=model.fit(X_train_lstm, y_train_lstm, epochs = num_epochs, batch_size = 128,shuffle=False,verbose=1,validation_data=[X_test_lstm,y_test_lstm],callbacks=[es])
```

Comment: What does it mean to "see 'y_pred' and 'y_true'"?

Comment: You cannot look at intermediate tensors if you use `model.compile` and `model.fit`, since they generate one graph internally. You need to use custom training loops with `GradientTape` to be able to see tensor values.

Comment: @DavidS see 'y_pred' and 'y_true means be able to see the tensor values. Just a sample of one batch

Comment: I found a solution to this issue. Thanks all

Comment: @RanKremer, by "see" I understand you mean something like print the values to the console or write them in a file, correct? Could you please share the solution you found?